# Pass param to font size inside strings.xml ANDROID

Tags: android, xml, string, font-size, android-screen-support

I create app with multiple screen support. In that case I'm using in textViews something like `android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"` to fit text size into many screen sizes and ratio . Anyway now I get a problem. Some parts of my strings need to be in different sizes and If I use dimens whole string have one size. There is an option to pass size param directly to strings.xml ? I mean something like:

`<string name="example_string"><font size="@param">bigger</font>normal</string>`

Comment: Do it using java with the help of Spannable Strings

Comment: You can differ them in `dimen` file using `dp` different sizes, for example: MDPI HDPI XHDPI ...

Comment: @Azhy man I think that you doesn't understand my questions. I'm using dimen, now I just need to for example increase header but this header is still part of one string in one textView

Answer (score 1):

You can use different string.xml for different sizes just like dimens.xml

```
<string name="text">
<![CDATA[<font size="20">Text in bigger font size 20.. </font><font 
size="10">Text in normal font size 10</font>]]> </string>
```

Comment: Maybe it's a way but creating a lot of strings.xml files doesn't sound so clever when font get sizes it has to be way to pass param from dimens